# MySQL and encoding result of strange character

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with relationship between MySQL and importing data into particular table. Whenever the form is requested, all data that have unicode chars into it is translated to other strange characters (question mark).

What I have tried uptil now:

- Set MySQL db / table to use *utf8_croatian_ci*
- Set meta-data into HTML to use *utf-8* encoding
- Query the `SET NAMES 'utf8'`
- Set all files to be encoded over UTF-8
- Query over `mysqli_set_charset()` (thanks for noticing HAL9k)
- Also added: `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`
- Tried editing `my.ini` and `php.ini` to set default charset to UTF-8

Letter transformation into DB:

- `č, ć` is translated into `?, ?` (HTML & DB)
- `ž` is translated into `�` (HTML, in database it's the real character 'ž' - not translated)

My meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Code (Pseudo):

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) or die("Error.");

// Spremanje rekorda preko UTF-8 karaktera
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");  // ovo je bolji način :-)

$selekt = "UPDATE proizvodi SET ..
                            WHERE   slug='...'";
```

Don't hate me for procedural style. :-) Cheers and thank you. Suggestions please.

Comment: Use [`mysqli::set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) instead of `SET NAMES ...`.

Comment: Change encoding of your php file, try utf8 without BOM

Comment: @HAL9000 whoops, forget to add that I have already tried that. Same problem. Thanks for notice, I removed the coded-comment for mysqli_set_charset().  

Aleks: I've tried like that but still not working. Notepad++ preference are settled to make them UTF8 without BOM on new file. Thanks!

Comment: Check if PHP script gets good characters. Add some feedback, for example: `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["unicode_variable_name"]);`

Comment: It does. I've just checked. Echo result is real character and not a questionmark. Any advice? This must be up to DB itself, right?

Comment: After UPDATE statement try issue SELECT (with the same connection) and output results with `echo`. Check if characters ok?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your db/table structure

utf8_general_ci

if this not work please find your current character set the code is below

```
    if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    } else {
        printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($link));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the output is: "Current character set: utf8"; so it's all ok up to DB charset.